# Android TableRows Align

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-tablelayout

First, Sorry for my English. I'm not a native speaker.

I've tried many ways to align my TextView in TableRow

```
    <TextView
            android:text="ท่านต้องการสิ่งใดเพื่อช่วยในการดูแลตนเอง"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"

            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"  />
        <!-- CheckList -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/answer_dialog_0309"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:width="300dp"               
            android:layout_height="150dp"


            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical"  />            
    </TableRow>
```

Here's my output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `TextView` should have it's `android:layout_height` attribute set to `match_parent`.

`android:layout_height="match_parent"` will cause the TextView to match the height of the TableRow.

The `android:gravity` attribute is used to set the gravity of the content within a View. It will not affect the size or positioning of the View itself.

Thus it would be:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/answer_dialog_0309"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:width="300dp"               
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to align the TextView itself and not its content by using layout_gravitiy="center"